# Flutter: Flickering when swipe happens with lottie/gif animations on slides

Tags: flutter, debugging, mobile, swipe, lottie

I have created certain slides with [liquid_swipe](https://pub.dev/packages/liquid_swipe) with each slide having a **Lottie** animation.
When I slide from ith slide to i+1th a background flicker happens.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Some user suggestions:

> Seems like **PageReveal** widget internally is causing this flicker but
> the fact that only Lottie Widget is flickering but not the entire
> screen, conflicts it.

[image]

Comment: Obvious question, but did you check the Lottie animation works at all without flickering? If you put it on a single screen without everything else, for example.

Comment: Yes I did, in that cases it works perfect, it's a bug a lot of people are searching for a solution for this error!